# Auto-increment dates in two cells if date has passed

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

**Overview:**

I'm not a programmer but I managed to get some serious coding into a Gsheets to track my teams project, so we have multiple-variable dropdown menus and integration with google calendar to track projects development and all that.

**Why I'm at stackoverflow:**

I kind of lack the knowledge to start the code from the scratch, I usually find spare parts of code through forums on the internet and clue them together and it usually works surprisingly well, but this time I couldn't find much informtation.

**What I need:**

I have 5 cells, and we can put as below,

Date start - Date end - date code* - number** - Priority***

> *script to add the date range to gcalendar
>
> ** & *** The number is an array that's based on the word written on the priority cell, for example: If priority is written *Weekly* them
>   the number colunm will show *7* on the cell to the left and them it
>   goes. (monthly = 30 and blablabla...)

---

So I'd like to know if someone could give a hand with a script that would work *(at least in my head)* as following:

If I set the priority to weekly, it will show 7 on the number colunm and them, every time the "Date end" has passed, it will automatically add 7 days to the "Date start" and "Date end" again.

That way I could keep the projects on a loop where I'll be able to track them constatly.

Thanks in advance for any insights provided,

---

ps: I've seen some posts about this on sql, but I have no idea also on how to take advantage of the proposals that were presented there.

Edit: 
[Spreadsheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGmFN.png)
eDIT2:
[Spreadsheet with a increment colunm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zudzt.png)

Comment: Instead of lengthy verbal description, please show us the sample Excel data set, describe business logic pertinent to this data, include your code and highlight the issue.

Comment: @AlexBell better now ?

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to the data set and description, you probably do not need any VBA as the increment could be achieved by adding +1 to the reference pointing to previous cell. For example, assuming cell A1 is formatted as Date, enter in cell B1: `=A1+1` , then in cell C1: `=B1+1` and so on. The result should be as shown below

```
A           B           C      
9/1/2017    9/2/2017    9/3/2017
```

It could be further extended with simple logic allowing do display incremented value only if the previous cell is not empty, like : `=IF(A1,A1+1,"")`

In your case, it could be cell F1 containing `=IF(E1,E1+1,"")`.

FYI, the underlying value of Date is just an Integer value (Time is represented as decimal part), so the arithmetic operations could be applied.

More generic solution would be based on the Excel `DATE()` Worksheet formula as shown in sample shown below (adding 1 mo. to the date entered in cell A1):

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1)+1, DAY(A1))
```

In order to implement additional logic, you may consider using Excel Worksheet `IF()` statement like for example, cell B1 containing:

```
=A1+IF(C1="week",7,1)

A           B           C
9/1/2017    9/8/2017    week
```

so based on the `IF()` condition it will add either 7 days if C1 contains the word "week" or 1 day otherwise. It could be further extended with nested `IF()`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the insight, but, would this generate a loop based on changes on the priority cell ?

Also, will it update after the "end" date has passed ?

The idea is to automate the date change to reduce mistakes, because today my team has to change the starting date and the end date by hand, the only thing I could achieve by now was to change the cell color if the date is older than today.

Comment: This concept you proposed I had in mind attributing values to a word like in a array, but I found out that it wouldn't generate a loop.

So weekly would be +7, monthly +30, but it at the end, it wouldn't update the start/ end date.

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't quite understand the "loop" issue: if you change the value in the reference cell (E1), the change will be automatically reflected (autoincremented) in cell F1. Regards,

Comment: Yes, it will auto increment on F1, I understand your point, it's a nice and simple solution, I liked it.

Do you know how could I improve it by using a word attributed to a value ? I mean, based on the word at the H colunm, It will set by how much it should be increased.

Like, on colunm H in have a dropdown with Weekly,Monthly,Semester etc.

Comment: Got the first part working, now just need to attribute values to the words

Comment: Found out that It will not work as intended, at least not as how I'm using it, let me explain.

Comment: The idea of the loop is that it changes the days automatically, I mean.
I set day 09/05/2017 to 09/07/2017 to follow up a process, if I go with your proposal, when I change the first date, it will change the second and will maintain the 2 days gap for the activity to be done, that's nice.

But I'd like to make the word "Weekly" to change the "Start date" whenever it has passed, incrementing it by 7, for example.

Comment: I placed another picture (edit2), to see if might be able to help.

Comment: The idea would be,
If "fup start" is older than today, them, increment it by "Weekly" (value of 7, so the activity is changed to the next week) and them for the "fup end" it would change by the same amount to preserve the gap/time for the activity to be done.

Comment: This comment thread became too lengthy. I would kindly remind you that SO is not a project development workspace, so please accept the answer if satisfied and post another question pertinent to a different problem (pls include your VBA code or Excel worksheet functions instead of verbal description and clearly highlight the problematic part). Thanks and regards,